# How to set value for a variable in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using JSR223 Sampler and trying for arithmetic operations..

```
try {
    setStrictJava(true);
    int a=1;
    int b=2;
    int c = a+b;
    vars.put("c",c);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    log.error("something wrong", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Getting following error..

```
2018-12-18 18:19:59,554 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``try{ setStrictJava(true); int a=1; int b=2; int c = a+b; vars.put("c",c); } catc . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method put( java.lang.String, int ) not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables' : at Line: 6 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``try{ setStrictJava(true); int a=1; int b=2; int c = a+b; vars.put("c",c); } catc . . . '' : vars .put ( "c" , c ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``try{ setStrictJava(true); int a=1; int b=2; int c = a+b; vars.put("c",c); } catc . . . '' at line number 6
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``try{ setStrictJava(true); int a=1; int b=2; int c = a+b; vars.put("c",c); } catc . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method put( java.lang.String, int ) not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables' : at Line: 6 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``try{ setStrictJava(true); int a=1; int b=2; int c = a+b; vars.put("c",c); } catc . . . '' : vars .put ( "c" , c )
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert to string your numeric variable:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
vars.put("c", c.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You either need to [convert your variable to String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-) in order to be able to use [vars.put()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function like:

```
vars.put("c", String.valueOf(c));
```

or use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function instead

```
vars.putObject("c", c);
```

---

Also be aware that you should be using [Groovy language in the JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), in this case you will have to remove `setStrictJava(true);` line otherwise your code will not work.